# how to write function in VDM++ language

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, vdm++

I am making a translator of VDM++. which converts VDM++ code in C++. For that i am doing mapping of VDM++ into C++.

I want to know how to write a function in VDM++?

for example.

```
float functionX(int var1,float var2){
int x= 10;
float y= 0.3;
return y;
}
```

how i write this code in VDM++?

Comment: After 30 seconds on google, having never heard of vdm++ before, I've got an idea. If you do the same you probably will too.

Comment: @duttI search about it a lot. And got a lot of material but i am not getting the syntax of VDM.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Development_Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example function is slightly unusual, in that it does not use its parameters, but in general a VDM function could look like this:

```
func: int * real -> real
func(var1, var2) ==
    var1 + var2;
```

Note that the function is "pure" in the sense that it is just an expression involving its parameters (it can also reference constants and call other functions). For more details, I would recommend you look at the Language Reference Manual.

Comment: can you translate that function in C++ please?

Comment: I suppose it would be something like:

double func(int var1, double var2)
{
    return var1 + var2;
}

Comment: If you Google for "VDM Language Reference Manual", the first hit is the document you need for more information.